# Paypal Discount When purchasing two + items (not two instances of same object)

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, discounts

Paypal has listed out methods for discounts such as :

```
discount_amount
```

Optional
Discount amount associated with an item.
It must be less than the selling price of the item. If you specify discount_amount and discount_amount2 is not defined, then this flat amount is applied regardless of the quantity of items purchased.
Valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons.

```
discount_amount2
```

Optional
Discount amount associated with each additional quantity of the item.
It must be equal to or less than the selling price of the item. A discount_amount must also be specified as greater than or equal to 0 for discount_amount2 to take effect.
Valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons.

I understand that you can have a discount associated with the amount of the same object inside of the cart.  I'm wondering if anyone knows a way or method to allow a discount to show up if you say add 3 items or 5 items.  Basically the situation is users have the option of signing up for either 1-4 courses.  If a user signs up for 1  normal price(lets say 30) occurs.  If a second is added they would receive a 10 dollar discount on the tuition(50). Than if a third is added it would show up as the regular method (resulting in 90)  However if a fourth is added it would be a charge of 3 courses plus 50.  (95).  Is there any solution to presenting this to paypal to update based on amount of items (each being different items[different course dates and names]) included in your cart?

Comment: I would love to know how to do this.  It's driving me crazy.  I have a customer that needs this.  I would add a rebate item, but I don't know how to control that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for the whole cart and not just the item use `discount_amount_cart`

Remember `discount_amount_1` has to be less in value than `amount_1`